# Storing data from arduino in mysql using python on raspberrypi

Tags: python, mysql, python-2.7, arduino, raspberry-pi

I have referred the code from this link:http://www.daviom.com/tutorial/tutorial-store-arduino-data-with-raspberry-pi-to-mysql/
The arduino code is working correctly however the python code executes by giving the following  output but does not store value in the database , even the tx light on the arduino blinks while the python code is executing but the values are not getting stored in the database

[image]

pls someone help me out as i am new to python

the output after uncommenting  print statement in the python code 
[image]  #print("value received:"+string+ " interpreted as: project Id = "+projectId+" and value = "+value)
is not displaying any  output
the values from the arduino are inconsistent and the second print statement 
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: How do you know they are not stored ?. The output you get seems the normal one after finishing the 50-cycles loop of the script.

Comment: i checked the database but no values where stored in it

Comment: Did you check the loop runs ? (uncomment prints in the loop to check what the program is writing).

Comment: i have un commented the loop the  print(ardString) statement is outputing value coming form the arduino , but the string is inconsistent sometimes it displays as : x-50 and sometimes as x50 the second print statement "print("value received:"+string+ " interpreted as: project Id = "+projectId+" and value = "+value)" is not displaying any output i have attached the screenshot of the output after uncommenting print statement as you said .

Comment: check **all** prints: be sure you enter the `if len(valueMatrix)> 1` which is neccesary to insert data on the dbase. If `ardString` is just what you report then it would not comply with the if because valueMatrix would be equal to 1. Another question: where `x` in `x50` comes from ? On the arduino code you should have `Serial.println("xyz123 " + tempAsString);`. This should return something like "xyz123 50" in `ardString` . Did you wrote exactly this ? Did you noticed the space after 123 ?

Comment: i changed the string from xyz123 to x thats why x i didnt understand what you meant by change your if len(valueMatrix)>1

Comment: After looking at your edit, I think you forgot a blank space in your arduino code. sometimes you get x-50 (value is -50) and sometimes something like x232 (value is 232). You need `x -50` or `x 200` (note the space). This is a problem of what you wrote on the arduino code as said above.

Comment: thanks i am just trying that sapce think what you said i will report as soon as i complete it

Comment: i got the following error "x 449.5

['x', '449.5\r\n']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "arduino2mysql.py", line 34, in <module>
    print("value received:"+string+ " interpreted as: project Id = "+projectId+" and value = "+value)
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'module' objects" and if i comment the second print statement i get the error in the screenshot that i have uploaded in the main post

Comment: please, this is going neverending with new questions in a row. Please accept my answer for the solved problems and write a new question on the mysql problem. Note that the mysql problem is already discussed in the blogpost you link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your arduino code

```
Serial.println("xyz123 " + tempAsString);
```

sends

```
"xyz123 value"     ("value" is any float value)
```

to your rasbperry and this string is stored in `ardString`.
If instead of the above you wrote:

```
Serial.println("xyz123" + tempAsString);
```

then

```
ardString  ->  "xyz123value"
```

and

```
valueMatrix = ardString.split(' ')  -> ["xyz123value"]
```

Thus, len(valueMatrix) is equal to 1 so that nothing is writen on the database.

---

Relative to the next error you got in the print when you corrected the arduino code, modify the print statement to (change `string` to `ardString`):

```
print("value received:" + ardString + " interpreted as: project Id = " + projectId + " and value = " + value)
```

Comment: thanks bro at last i had to only delete the foreign key from the code and thats it it worked ,anyways thanks for all your guidance it helped we learn what the code does